# What folders need to be uploaded to deploy a Razzle app on Azure?

Tags: server-side-rendering, razzle

I have created a Razzle app using npx create-razzle-app command, it works fine on my local machine. As I am new to Azure, I am struggling to deploy it on Azure. What folders needs to be uploaded on Azure?

I tried uploading build folder, but I got NPM packages related issues hence I uploaded node_modules from my local folder to build folder in Azure, but I get internal server error on my site page. I had also included web.config file shared in other stackoverflow answer, but not working.

Just to ensure my Azure configuration is proper, I deployed basic node.js demo app from Microsoft Azure tutorials and it worked fine. I observed that it was just simple app and they made zip package that included package.json and index.js, but in my case I want to deploy production bundle generated by 'npm run build' command.

I have also gone through some Razzle runtime PORT related issues, but not getting from where to start.